# Use of the verb “ consider”

Tags: verbs

> I was considered to have completed my part . Thanks to my team.

Or

> I was counted to have completed my part. Thanks to my team.

In this sentence,I tried to say ;There is a project which should be completed by my team. Everyone would complete a part of project but I did not complete my part but as people in my team completed the project As people in my team completed the project my teacher ignore whether I did it or not . Even id it is partly completed because of me . Can I use consider in this way to explain this situation? I mean I try to say the sentence below as passive voice :

> The teacher considered me to have completed my part"

Comment: Perhaps you can say: *Thanks to my team, I was considered to have completed my part in the project.* This suggests that if it hadn't been for them, you would have been considered as not having done your part.

Comment: counted and consider are not synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express all the details described in the paragraph, there is no way that you can do that in one sentence.

If you say "I was considered to have completed my part." It just means that "Someone has the opinion that I have completed my part". It can't mean all the details about teams and teachers.

The incomplete sentence "Thanks to my team" doesn't make much sense here.  Are you thanking your team? Are you acknowledging their part in your success.  The paragraph suggests something different.

As far as I can tell what you should say is somthing like

> I did not complete my part in the project. However, the project was successful, due to the efforts of my team.

Comment: Actually I want to say your sentence. Couldn’t ı use count or consider for this.

Comment: Why is using the word consider important?

Comment: Maybe I try to say it by thinking in Turkish. We use for this situation mostly “count”.

Comment: @JamesK I think you should correct: *due to my the efforts of my team.*

Comment: To my AE ear, "Thanks to my team, I was credited (by the teacher) with having completed my part" more closely aligns with your intent.  Credit, in this context, can help distinguish the recognition you get for completing the work vs evidence that you did the work.  Thanks to my team up front means that what follows is dependent on their actions.